# how to fix '403 (Forbidden)' on a $http.get request to etherpad

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, etherpad

[header][1]
[header][2]

i am trying to send a get request to  etherpad  hosted in a different domain.   the OPTIONS preflight  request goes through but the get request returns  403 status.

however  when  i install  CORS for chrome extension  the request goes through

when i install cors chrome extension the request goes through

here is my code:
/* ........ export draft to html/pdf/word ........ */

````
            //get content for this template
            var url = Drafting.domain + Drafting.port + '/p/' + Drafting.padID + '/export/html?' + 'apikey=' + Drafting.apikey;

            $http.get(url).then(function(response, status){             
                if(typeof(callback)==='function' && callback)
                {
                    callback(response.data);
                }
            });         
        ```}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/25dsj.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivHnn.png
````

Answer (score 0):

i just passed 'withCredentials:true' together with the url and then modified the importexport.js inside the etherpad files  where 'AccessControlAllowOrigin' was set to '*' i replaced it with a specific domain and it worked.